# ListView Not updating when inserting value in database from fragment

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, fragment

I create a bottomsheet using BottomSHeetDialogfragment i have 2 textbox and 1 button called save button on my bottomsheet after pressing save button my data inserting to sqlite database successfully, and i have a listview on my mainactivity when save button is pressed the data inserted to database successfully but my listview not updating the inserted value automatically

now how can i update my listview automatically?

my adapter class is ...

```
public class MainListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> taskList;
    ArrayList<String> detailList;

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public MainListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> taskList, ArrayList<String> detailList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.taskList = taskList;
        this.detailList = detailList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return taskList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_activity_list_view, parent, false);
        }

        TextView tasktitleTv = convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_title_tv_id);
        TextView taskDetailsTv = convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_detail_tv_id);
        final CheckBox checkBox = convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_checkbox_id);

        convertView.setClickable(true);
        convertView.setFocusable(true);
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.menuitem_background);


        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        tasktitleTv.setText(taskList.get(position));
        taskDetailsTv.setText(detailList.get(position));


        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    taskList.remove(position);
                    detailList.remove(position);
                    MainListViewAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    return;
                }
                if (isChecked) {
                    buttonView.toggle();
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

and my mainActivity.java class is

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView taskHeaderTv;
    public ListView mainListview;
    private MainListViewAdapter mainListViewAdapter;

    private FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
    private BottomAppBar bottomAppBar;

    private DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        taskHeaderTv = findViewById(R.id.task_header_tv_id);
        floatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.floating_action_button);
        bottomAppBar = findViewById(R.id.bottomAppBar);

        fabClick();
        bottomAppBarClick();

        // set list view content
        dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        ArrayList<String> taskList = dataBaseHelper.getAllTitle();
        ArrayList<String> detailList = dataBaseHelper.getALlDetails();

        mainListview = findViewById(R.id.main_activity_listview_id);
        mainListViewAdapter = new MainListViewAdapter(this, taskList, detailList);
        mainListview.setAdapter(mainListViewAdapter);

        mainListview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        mainListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

and my Fragment class is

```
public class ListItemInputFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.DialogStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_item_input, container, false);

        final EditText newTaskEt, detailsEt;
        TextView savBtn;
        newTaskEt = view.findViewById(R.id.new_task_et_id);
        detailsEt = view.findViewById(R.id.details_et_id);
        savBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.save_btn_id);

        savBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String title = newTaskEt.getText().toString();
                String detail = detailsEt.getText().toString();

                DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getContext());
                long row = dataBaseHelper.insertData(title, detail);

                if (row == -1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Data not inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                dismiss();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: What to show listview , after dataBaseHelper.insertData in your fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Since onCreate is only called ones the MainActivity has been created (but not after dismissing bottom shield), you can update your list in onResume which is called after dismissal of bottom shield.

### MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    mainListViewAdapter.taskList = dataBaseHelper.getAllTitle();
    mainListViewAdapter.detailList = dataBaseHelper.getALlDetails();
    mainListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

But, I really recommend you to check Android Architecture Components and Room. (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture) MVVM (Model - View - View Model) with using LiveData makes your life much easier.

Comment: thanks for suck good kind of information. and yes a come up with my solution with another way but i think yours is better than me. thank u very much for response